# how to take index list from groupby dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

[image]

i have this result from group by my df, how can i take a list name of City from this result df?
i found this solving problem but i dont know how this for loop works:

[image]

i think result is 2 part, index list and a new dataframe, so when input city,df in groupby df. it will return first list is city and the other in df. Is it true?
but the type of df when i print(type(df)) is list, i thought it containt all the list except index list i had push into city. but when i try for loop with city,df,df1,df2,.. error appear :(

Comment: No images, please. Copy paste your `df` to the question.

Comment: sorry, first time ask a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i have this result from group by my df, how can i take a list name of City from this result df?

```
result = all_data.groupby('City').sum()
```

`result` is `Series`, where `City` is converted to `index`, so simpliest is:

```
cities = result.index
```

For plotting it is more easier if use [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html), by default index is plotting in `axis=x`:

```
result.plot.bar()
```

---

You can rewrite your list comprehension for [loop by groupby object](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#iterating-through-groups), so here `city` is grouped column unique values and `df` is group:

```
for city, df  in all_data.groupby('City'):
    print (city)
    print (df)
```

So if extract `city` get unique values by `City` column, which is converted to `index` after aggregate `sum`.

```
cities = [city for city, df  in all_data.groupby('City')]
```

Comment: yeah, what i want to know is "cities = result.index" . I tried to find how to get index of df.groupby but can;t find anything. thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Try converting it into a dataframe first and then use df for your calculations:

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data.groupby(['City']))

Comment: yeah, i just want to get list of cities name to set xlabel and draw bar plot

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the list of cities just reset the index:

```
result = all_data.groupby('city').sum().reset_index()
cities = result ['city']
```

It seems as if your are trying to plot the sales per city. This could be achieved with the result dataframe directly:

```
all_data.plot(kind='bar', x='city', y='sales')
```

Comment: it's seem not work with me. tks